# Unsupported console error with Ubuntu 18.04 in WSL

Tags: command-line

I enter my username in Ubuntu, but it doesn't take it. Instead I see the following error:

[image: Unsupported Console]

What does it mean?

Comment: This appears to be a Windows error - see for example [Bash does not start – Error “Unsupported console settings” in Windows 10](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/bash-does-not-start-unsupported-console-settings-windows-10/)

Comment: I cant read it, please write down the error message!

Answer (score 2):

This is a common item for people using WSL. Fortunately, it's not too difficult to fix:

1. Open the Run dialog (<kbd>Win+R</kbd>) and type `cmd.exe`
2. When Command Prompt appears, click the upper-left icon and choose "Properties":
   [image: Command Prompt - Properties]
3. On the "Options" tab (the first one) look at the bottom where it says "Use Legacy Console" and ensure it's unchecked
4. Press [OK] to save the changes

You will need to restart your Command Prompt (and probably WSL) for this to take effect.

Comment: THANK YOU....It's works